# Laravel Обновление связанной модели для только что созданной модели

Tags: laravel5

Есть две связанные модели:

Модель User

```
public function ico()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Icon::class);
  }
```

И модель Icon

```
public function user()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
  }
```

В модели Icon имеются уже заполненные поля `NAME, CODE` а также пустое поле `user_id`

Как при добавлении нового Юзера добавить его `id` в поле `user_id` модели `Icon` где имя иконки равно реквесту.

В контроллере добавляю так:

```
$user = new User;
        $user ->name            = $request->name;
        $user ->location        = $request->location;
        $user ->save();
```

Такая конструкция не работает

```
$ico = Icon::where('name', $request->ico );
        $ico->user_id = $user->id;
        $user = User::find($user->id);
        $ico = $user->ico()->update($ico);
```

ошибка

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::update()
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот так
$user->ico->update($ico);
$ico = $user;

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде делается.

```
$user = User::create($requrest->all());
$user->ico->update($ico);
```

Comment: ошибка: Call to a member function update() on null

Comment: $ico = Icon::where('name', $request->ico ); эта строка возвращает null, хотя я точно знаю что в реквесте есть даные

Comment: $ico = Icon::where('name', $request->ico )->get(); добавил гет, сделал дд, теперь возвращает данные, НО все равно ошибка вылазиет такая же

Comment: Сделал так, все работает. Спасибо за помощь! ` $ico = Icon::where('name', $request->ico )->first();
        $ico->user_id = $userID;
        $ico->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в том, что перед тем, как редактировать - нужно взять объект, воспользовавшись функцией first().

```
$ico = Icon::where('name', $request->ico )->first();
$ico->user_id = $user->id;
$user = User::find($user->id);
$ico = $user->ico()->update($ico);
```